# model.predict yield yhat of bad dimension

Tags: lstm, tensorflow2.0, dimensions

I reuse an old code who was perfectly functionnal 3 mount ago to train a new LSTM model on new set of data.

my data have these shapes:

```
X_train =  [21500, 5, 4]
y_train = [21500, 1]
```

trainning model seem to work well, it finish with a single

```
tensor_input = Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]), name='main_inputs')

xy = LSTM(6, activation='softsign',
          kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(),
          return_sequences=False, stateful=False,
          name='Hlayer1')(tensor_input)

xy = Dropout(rate=.2)(xy)

Dense(y_train_shape[1], activation='linear')
```

but when I try to predict with

```
yhat = model.predict(x_test)
x_test = [1350,1]
```

I get

```
yhat = [1350, 5, 1]
```

I build my code this way since 5 years but first time I get this!??!

Comment: What is the shape of x_test? If it's (1350, 1) then ` model.predict(x_test)` gives an error message

Comment: @AndrzejO yes x_test is [1350,1] but I don't get error here, only bad dimension yhat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never find the trouble, just reinstall Tensorflow and now it work!?